# slow loading site after IIS restart

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, global-asax, app-offline.htm

When my site is out of service(IIS Restart - Service unavailable), it takes about 10 to 20 minutes to come up my site,In this case,If I put 'app_offline.htm' in the root of the site comes up in just a few seconds.

Now I want to perform automatic operation.What is the solution?

Comment: "Now I want to perform automatic operation" - what operation do you want to perform?

Comment: if site is down,app_offline.htm is automatically created in the root and when the site is up(Application_Start), remove or rename it.

Comment: I never used that feature, but looking at [ScottGu's post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/10/06/426755.aspx) I doubt it going to help you as it looks like while file is there requests will not be send to the application and - so no "Application_Start".

Comment: Have you looked into why your site takes 10-20 mins to start?

Comment: Only when IIS restarted, the speed drops for start again!I do not know where is the problem? If I put 'app_offline.htm' in the root of the site and after a few seconds delete it, manually,comes up in just a few seconds